# How to delete an entire row in a csv file when a specific string is entered in python

Tags: python, csv

I want to know how to delete an entire row in a csv file when a specific string is entered into python. For example, if the number 8 is entered, the row in the csv file where 8 is the first character is deleted.

Explanations in simple terms are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Declare your approach for reading csv files.

Comment: I would do it like this: 
#1 read current line
#2 check if first string equals number 8
#3 skip this line
#4 read all other lines
#5 write all lines that have been read (which is all but the one with 8) into a new file, or overwrite the existing one
You might want to tell us where exactly you need help with.